# AS3 | How to stop replay my app when press ENTER?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

when i press <kbd>Enter</kbd> my app replay. I'm not added event listeners for this. How do I stop this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is in-built feature ONLY WHEN YOU ARE DEBUGGING (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> by default)

open [your flash document name here].swf if you want to use enter for test